# Regular expression: is there a way to parse a positive integer?

Tags: regex

I've coded that in python but the language doesn't matter here:

```
  pattern = re.compile("^params:([0-9]+)$")
  f = open(in_file, 'r')
  try:
    while True:
      v = f.readline()
      if not v:
        break
      found = pattern.search(v)
      if found:
        pdb.gimp_message(str(found.group(1)))
        break
  finally:
    f.close()
```

The problem is that the regexp validates:

```
params:0
params:01654
params:000000000000
```

and I don't want them to be valid, so I have to add this condition: `if found.group(1)>0:` and I was thinking: maybe a smart regular expression could avoid this.

Any idea?

Comment: What's wrong with those examples?  Are you trying to avoid anything with leading zeros?

Comment: I just wanted to give some examples that don't fit "positive integer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the only condition is that there shouldn't be a zero at the start.

```
^params:([1-9][0-9]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use combination of string and integer casting.
first you cast into integer and then into string and compare the 2 strings.